# Pipenv lock failed when adding numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pipenv, pipfile

Goal: Creating Pipfile & Pipfile.lock with **numpy**

Error: *AttributeError: 'String' object has no attribute 'update'*

without numpy I run `pipenv lock` successfully

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]
autopep8 = "*"
pep8 = "*"
pytest = "*"
pytest-datadir = "*"
pytest-mock = "*"

[packages]
Jinja2 = "==3.1.2"
pandas = "==1.3.5"
PyYAML = "==6.0.1"
click = "==8.1.7"
google-ads = "==22.0.0"
db-dtypes = "==1.1.1"
pyarrow = "==12.0.0"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
```

when running `pipenv graph` it shows that numpy is installed as a dependency(installed: 1.21.6), but somehow I should include in pipfile explicitly to be installed on a Docker image

I tried using numpy = "*" with a wildcard and also numpy = "==1.21.6"

Comment: In my case it was caused by python referencing python 2.7. Fixed it by installing `python-is-python3`.